# How to show ScalaTest tests nicely in TeamCity

Tags: java, scala, maven, teamcity, scalatest

I am new to Scala and integrating it in an existing Java project.

The project is built with Maven (already configured the pom.xml successfully to compile and both Java and Scala code and run both lang's tests in a single project).

Our TeamCity Server has a Maven build step.

I have created a new unit test in ScalaTest, but when TeamCity runs the build, it does not identify this test as a test, so I can only see the result in the full build log, but not in the "Tests" tab.

Searched for a ScalaTest plugin for TeamCity but did not found any.

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *"see the result in the full build log"*, where do you expect to see it?

Comment: like JUnit tests are shown, in the "Tests" tab

Comment: There is a plugin for SBT, but since you're using Maven, you might need to use the JUnit test runner: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_junit_runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this in a pretty simple way. It turns out that the maven plugin for scalatest can generate reports in junit format. I changed the output folder for those reports to the same as the report folder of the surefire  plugin (target/surefire-reports) and that's it.

Actually the basic sample at [scalatest guide](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin) shows the correct configuration.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need XML Reporting Build feature to be added to your build configuration. If that feature is not available in Build Features, then try saving your test result file as in %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%test_results.xml

Teamcity I think should pick this file and display it in Test tab. You might need to define this file as one of the artefact.